# Calling non-static method reference on an object with an argument

Tags: java, events, event-handling, java-8

I'm creating an event handling framework and would like to do the following:

```
// E: event listener interface, T: event class
class EventManager<E, T> {

    ArrayList<E> listeners = new ArrayList<E>();

    // `method` is some sort of reference to the method to call on each listener. There is no `MethodReference` type, I just put it there as I'm not sure what type should be in its place
    protected void notifyListeners(MethodReference method, T eventObj) {
        for (E listener : listeners) // call `method` from `listener` with `eventObj` as an argument
   }
}

class SpecialisedEventManager extends EventManager<SomeListener, SomeEvent> {

    // Some method that would want to notify the listeners
    public void foo() {
        ...
        // I would like onEvent() to be called from each listener with new SomeEvent() as the argument
        notifyListeners(SomeListener::onEvent, new SomeEvent());
        ...
    }

    // Some other method that would want to notify the listeners
    public void bar() {
        ...
        notifyListeners(SomeListener::onOtherEvent, new SomeEvent());
        ...
    }

}

interface SomeListener {
    public void onEvent(SomeEvent event);
    public void onOtherEvent(SomeEvent event);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to reference the `onEvent()` and `onOtherEvent()` methods so that they are called from each listener object with the proper argument. Any ideas?

Comment: How does the `MethodReference` interface look like?

Comment: @Flown It doesn't actually exist, I just put it there to conform with Java's syntax. I'm not sure what type should be in its place.

Comment: And why don’t you [search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/package-summary.html) for an appropriate interface? All you have to do is looking for parameters and return type…

Comment: @Holger I did search but I was unsure how I would apply the consumer to the listener object and the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method reference is just a way to implement a functional interface, so you have to either, define yourself an appropriate interface or [search the predefined types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/package-summary.html) for a match.

Since your listener method consumes a target listener instance and an event object and doesn’t return a value, [`BiConsumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) is an appropriate type:

```
protected void notifyListeners(BiConsumer<E,T> method, T eventObj) {
    for(E listener: listeners)
        method.accept(listener, eventObj);
}
```

The method references `SomeListener::onEvent` and `SomeListener::onOtherEvent` have the form [“Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#PageTitle) where the caller provides the target instance to invoke the method on, similar to the lambda expressions `(l,e) -> l.onEvent(e)` and `(l,e) -> l.onOtherEvent(e)`, which is why the target instance becomes the first functional parameter.